# two kind of description of model.compile get the different results

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

#### have already tried

The data pipeline and model build function is right

#### code

The code is https://gist.github.com/MaoXianXin/cd398521546d967560942e702c243ba7

I want to know why this two kind of description of model.compile get the different results.

**see the accuracy**

`model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.01), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])`

```
Epoch 1/50
2019-05-27 13:53:20.280605: I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:153] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0 locally
468/468 [==============================] - 6s 12ms/step - loss: 14.4332 - acc: 0.1045 - val_loss: 14.4601 - val_acc: 0.1029
Epoch 2/50
468/468 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 14.4354 - acc: 0.1044 - val_loss: 14.4763 - val_acc: 0.1023
Epoch 3/50
468/468 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 14.4359 - acc: 0.1044 - val_loss: 14.4714 - val_acc: 0.1026
Epoch 4/50
468/468 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 14.4359 - acc: 0.1044 - val_loss: 14.4682 - val_acc: 0.1028
```

`model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])`

```
Epoch 1/50
2019-05-27 13:51:16.122054: I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:153] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0 locally
468/468 [==============================] - 5s 12ms/step - loss: 3.6567 - acc: 0.7388 - val_loss: 0.0732 - val_acc: 0.9791
Epoch 2/50
468/468 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0812 - acc: 0.9760 - val_loss: 0.0449 - val_acc: 0.9854
Epoch 3/50
468/468 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0533 - acc: 0.9836 - val_loss: 0.0428 - val_acc: 0.9869
Epoch 4/50
468/468 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0426 - acc: 0.9871 - val_loss: 0.0446 - val_acc: 0.9872
Epoch 5/50
468/468 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0376 - acc: 0.9886 - val_loss: 0.0449 - val_acc: 0.9867
```